# Django and jQuery: timing

Tags: jquery, django

In Django, I want a webpage that times how long it takes the user to press a button, from the time the page first loads, until the time the button is clicked. I then want to pass that value back to a view function, so that I can store it in a database.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    $('#myform').submit(function(){
        var elapsed = new Date().getTime() - start;
    });
});
```

And here is my Django template:

```
<form id='myform' method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="time" value=????? />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

What do I put in place of the `?????`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost got it. Keep `value` empty initially, and then set it in your jQuery `submit` callback.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    $('#myform').submit(function(){
        var elapsed = new Date().getTime() - start;
        // set the value for time when the form is submitted
        $('#myform input[name="time"]').val(elapsed);
    });
});
```